# Where can I get a box a ceiling fan light?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

Does anyone know where I can get a box for a ceiling fan light. I have a ceiling fan with a light but would like to replace the light with a ceiling lamp I have. The current box won't work because there are 3 lamps sticking out the sides and I need just one hole on the bottom.

The fan and light are both controlled with one wall switch and each are controlled a separate pull cord. I know this is unusual but I have decades of experience in unusual and can always revert it. 8 also know that I can't just slap the lamp onto the bottom of the fan.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by a box? Generally, light kits are bespoke to the particular model of fan in question

Comment: Are you saying to add a box below the fan where the lamps usually hang? , see 3 phases comment above, other than that a bell box could be used I guess.+

Comment: Yes, "to add a box below the fan where the lamps usually hang," is exactly what I mean. I need something to connect the wiring from the fan to the ceiling light that I want to replace the light that is currently hanging there now. I just cannot seem to find one that doesn't come without a light attached. And I want the lamp securely and properly attached.